# How do I use the jquery scrollbar paper plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins

I want to use [the jquery scrollbar paper plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/scrollbarpaper) to alter the style of scrollbars within the document. However the page for the plugin does not seem to have any documentation. How am I supposed to use this plugin (aside from including the js and css files the downloaded zip file gives you)?

Answer (score 1):

The [example page](http://www.lelieududesign.com/en/why-le-lieu-du-design) shows that all you need to do is use the jQuery plugin on any elements you want to have a custom scrollbar.

```
$('.use-scrollbarpaper').scrollbarPaper();
```

And this adds divs with classes `scrollbarpaper-track`, `scrollbarpaper-container` and `scrollbarpaper-drag` which I presume are styled by default in the CSS provided, so you can style them as required.

Comment: For some reason the jquery seems to be inserting the divs before the content with the selected class. It's not changing the style of the scroll bars. Am I doing something wrong? I'm acting it on a div with an `overflow:auto;` property.

Comment: Ok I just realized that that is how the plugin works, but for some reason the scrollbar that the plugin adds does not cover the default scroll bar. It's somewhere off to the side and I'm not sure why.

Comment: Is it possible to hide the original scroll bar which appears behind the plug in scrollbar?

Comment: The plugin doesn't give a height to the div with css class .scrollbarpaper-container which it should (<div class="scrollbarpaper-container">). Do give a height to this div and the original scrollbar should be covered by this div and "hidden" .... e.g http://goo.gl/Em2vU

Comment: add the css style like this: `div.scrollbarpaper-container{ height: 400px;}`

Answer (score 1):

The code and some examples can be found on the plugin's googlecode page:

http://code.google.com/p/scrollbarpaper/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk