# adding scrollbars

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My page has lots of scrollbars and gives my UI an old feeling. It doesn't suit the design at all. Is there any suggestions for improvement? Is there any thing to do so stylish scrollbars can be added on all browsers? Most of the plugins either work in webkit browsers or firefox. Is there any plugin which works in both ones? If possible IE too.

This one doesn't work in IE
http://manos.malihu.gr/tuts/jquery_custom_scrollbar.html

Comment: Yes, but you really shouldn't change things like this. Scrollbars, form elements, and the like are deliberately grounded in the UI of the operating system being used, and should only be changed with great reluctance. That said, I've used [jScrollPane](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/jScrollPane/jScrollPane.html) on client sites with success.

Comment: post some code, a printscreen or something

Comment: @Blazemonger I don't agree. [please check out this wonderful slider taking advantage of CSS3's "range" method, and also providing fallback to older browsers.](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#slider-vertical)

Comment: @Blazemonger I will check out http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/jScrollPane/basic.html and give you the feedback

Comment: I get the error "$drag[0] is undefined
[Break On This Error]  

maxY = trackHeight - $drag[0].offsetHeight;" inside the file jScrollPane.js while using the jscrollPane.. Wat cud be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery [scrollbarpaper](http://code.google.com/p/scrollbarpaper/source/browse/#svn/trunk) plugin is my favorite. It differs from other scroll bar plugins in that it just covers the scroll bar with a div instead of replacing the native browser functionality, allowing you to safely style out your scroll bar with css.

Example: http://www.lelieududesign.com/en/why-le-lieu-du-design

SO reference: [How do I use the jquery scrollbar paper plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7117472/1363726)

Comment: The scroll bar appears behind the one that we creates....its nt wrking the way as shown in the lelieudesign.com website..

Comment: You will most likely have to add your own css to get it looking right, can you post an example?

Comment: I took the example file from your link http://code.google.com/p/scrollbarpaper/source/browse/trunk/example1.html ... I need a small scroller about length 5px... IF I use that the background scroller(original one) can be seen behind the plugin scroller..

Comment: Unfortunately, since you are not replacing the scroll bar you have to expand the container div wide enough to cover the whole native scroll bar, however with enough css craftiness you can create an illusion that the scroll bar is thinner than it really is. Look at the css in the example I gave you, if you remove `div.scrollbarpaper-container {background-color:white;}` you will see how they hid the scroll.